# Finding a Jordan basis - choosing the right vector

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I'm trying to get a hold of it with various examples and simplify the process as much as possible.
For this one:
$A=\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$
it's quite obvious that the JNF is:
$J=J_{2}\left(1\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$

Now, to find the basis which consists $P$ s.t. $J=P^{-1}AP$, I'll denote $N=A-I$ and consecutively take the differnce between the kernels, meaning:

$\lambda=1\Rightarrow\ker N\\=\ker\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1\\
-1 & -1
\end{matrix}\right)=\text{Span}\left\{ v=\left(-1,1\right)\right\} \\\Rightarrow\ker N^{2}\setminus\ker N=\\=\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\text{Span}\left\{ v=\left(-1,1\right)\right\} \\(**)=\text{Span}\left\{ u=\left(-1,0\right)\right\} $

The thing is, in the stage denoted (**) I could have taken another 2 or 3 options of $u\in \mathbb R ^{2} \setminus \text{Sp}{(-1,1)}$ but only $(-1,0)$ gives me the desired $P$.

Right now I'm guessing and checking, but isn't there a systematic way to choose the right $u$? 
Also, supposed $n\geq3$ (still, a single eigenvalue), could I have generalized such method to any $n$?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that the second vector $v$ you find satisfies $(A-\lambda I)^2v = 0$ but $(A-\lambda I)v \ne 0$